# How widely supported are scheme-relative URIs in HTTP 301 redirects

Tags: http, redirect, location, uri

I want to have requests for the `www` subdomain or for alternate top-level domains redirected to one canonical URL.

To avoid HTTP/HTTPS issues, I figured the easiest way would be to just send a scheme-relative URI in the Location header, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: //example.com/
```

This seems to work fine in browsers, but the toy »validator« at http://no-www.org/ does not handle it correctly. Is this just a single badly written script, or is this behavior actually more common in scripts, crawlers, etc. out there?

Comment: [Relative URIs are now permitted in redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25643550/545127), so you can expect this to work in all future browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Location*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) expects an absolute URI:

> […] The field value consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
> Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```

Although most user agents will also accept relative URIs, you should stick to the specification and provide an absolute URI.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I totally missed that »absolute« part – I just assumed that any URL should work since all UAs I tested behaved as intended…

Comment: @klickverbot: The rule of thumb is: *Be tolerant with the input but be strict with the output.*

Comment: It's a bug in RFC 2616 that is fixed in the next revision: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/185

Comment: @Julian Reschke: Oh, really? But it won’t harm to use the stricter variant.

Comment: It's a bug in RFC 2616 but this RFC is still in force and it requires Location to have an absolute URL. There is a **[proposal](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26#section-7.1.2)** to change that but it is still awaiting approval.

Comment: rustyx - that proposal actually has been approved (in February)