# Chrome interprets relative redirect incorrectly in JSONP request

Tags: jquery, http, google-chrome, jsonp

My app is making a JSONP request to another domain using jquery.  It's calling `https://api/auth?redirect_to=%2Fping.json&authtoken=blahblah`

The server responds with a 302 to the relative URL "`/ping.json`".

Chrome then issues the error

```
[blocked] The page at https://www/pageurl ran insecure content from http://api/ping.json.
```

Is this correct behavior for some bizarre reason?  Something about how jquery invokes JSONP requests?  It seems to me that a very basic rule of HTTP is to not change the protocol when interpreting a relative URL, so this is surprising to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to conclude this is a Chrome bug.  I hope it gets fixed.

I'm open to other explanations.  If you have any idea why this behavior makes sense, please leave another answer.

Comment: I see this also. Interestingly enough, when I try to curl the same HTTPS endpoint on my server from the terminal it, curl also interprets the relative redirect as HTTP

Comment: Potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25643550/242426 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12436765/242426