# Protocol-relative URLs in redirects

Tags: http, http-redirect

Is it valid to use protocol-relative URLs in redirects?

Example:

`Location: //example.com/xxx`

Comment: What makes you think it's not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using protocol-relative URIs within "Location:" headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436669/using-protocol-relative-uris-within-location-headers)