# Ruby on Rails redirect_to relative URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, http

I have a Rails 4 app hosted behind Cloudflare, with the Flexible SSL option turned on, but no SSL between Cloudflare and the app servers which sit behind a load balancer.

So what happens is that, for instance when an user signs up using HTTPS and I redirect to a welcome page...

```
redirect_to :action => :welcome
```

... or ....

```
redirect_to "/users/welcome"
```

... Rails throws a HTTP header "Location: http://www.example.com/users/welcome". This obviously breaks the session and turns off SSL.

I have tried config.force_ssl but the browser goes into an infinite redirect loop.

I cannot switch the app to SSL because some parts of it have to use HTTP, and there's nothing that sensitive on the wire to justify switching, and also I have or 60 different websites built on this app, buying certificates for all of them would cost a small fortune. I just want Cloudflare's SSL because users think the "little green lock" means the site is safe and trustworthy :)

So, is there a way to make Rails redirect using relative URLs? as opposed to adding http://www.example.com... in front of each URL it redirects to?

TIA

Comment: FYI You can get free certificates from lets encrypt

Comment: I know but the amount of work required to set up certs for all sites will be significant, also it will complicate setting up new sites (which is now a point-and-click process)...too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easy fix for this when using Apache: rewrite the 30X headers

http://blog.delouw.ch/2009/10/29/302-redirect-behind-ssl-terminating-proxies/

```
Header edit Location ^http://(.*)$ https://$1
```

This question also has an answer about editing the header to remove the protocol and host, as opposed to redirecting everything:

[How to Rewrite Location Response Header in a Proxy Setup with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297233/how-to-rewrite-location-response-header-in-a-proxy-setup-with-apache)

```
Header edit Location "(^http[s]?://)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)" ""
```

Answer (score 3):

For a solution not using Apache, you can write the code as:

```
redirect_to :action => :welcome, :protocol => '//'
```

or,

```
redirect_to :action => :welcome, :only_path => true
```