# Rewrite response code in apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I am using apache server as a reverse proxy. The setup is as follows:
Client -> Apache Reverse Proxy -> Origin Server

My aim is to change the response code 200 for a particular URL which the reverse proxy receives from origin server to 302 response to client.

Origin (200 OK) -> Apache Reserver Proxy (302) -> Client

My apache server is as follows:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-09-16T13:13:53
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297233/how-to-rewrite-location-response-header-in-a-proxy-setup-with-apache