# PHP header function is not working

Tags: php, header

The following header function is not working. I ma trying to go to login if the user is not logged in -

```
    <?PHP
    if (logged_in() === false) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    }
    ?>
```

However if I do -

```
    <?PHP
    if (logged_in() === false) {
    echo"No user is logged in";
    }
    ?>
```

It does echo it and I can see that it says no user is logged in

It is basically just checking if there is a user logged in

```
    function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `login.php` is placed in the same folder

Comment: explain `logged_in()`

Comment: Yes login.php is in the same folder.

Comment: **wild guess**, `logged_in()` does some output, and `header()` then issue a warning and doesn't work

Comment: Agree with the earlier request for more info about logged_in(). Would you please update the question to include that function?

Comment: <?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>

Comment: You need to include `session_start();` as your first line of code after `<?php` in every affected/used file. Give that a try.

Comment: are you getting any warnings!

Comment: It worked I needed the ob_start and on_end_flush. Thanks a lot everyone for the help

Comment: @Fasilkk You should get the credit for this. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: @deceze why you voting -1 for correct answers??

Comment: @Fasil Output buffering is fixing the symptoms, not the problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/476.

Comment: @deceze I also mentioned that, "Make sure that there is no output(white-space also) in your code"

Answer (score 2):

Try to put **exit**() or **die**() after the header like

```
  if (logged_in() === false) {
      header('Location: login.php');
      exit();    //or die();
  }
```

But makesure that your login.php should be in the same folder

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out I needed the ob_start and ob_end_flush

Comment: @AvinashKunaparaju *Ahem*, `Fasil kk` figured it out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no output(white-space also) in your code.

you can use ob_start() and ob_end_flush() to clear out-put.

```
<?php ob_start();

 // code 

ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Although this solved the problem, it'd be good to explain why, for future visitors viewing this question.

Comment: @Daedalus Like 90% of the questions with answers on SO, most post a link to PHP.net anyway, so it's irrelevant. Give the guy a break.

Comment: @Daedalus... I added small explanation too.. I think that is enough to understand for all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include the fully qualified domain and path to the new url. There is a note on the official documentation for the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) indicating as such.

> Note:
>
> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a
>   relative one yourself:

This note also contains the following code sample.

```
<?php 
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */ 
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\'); 
$extra = 'login.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra"); 
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: Every browser supports relative URLs, and W3C or IETF is planning on changing the spec to say that it's allowed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250259/is-a-302-redirect-to-relative-url-valid-or-invalid