# HttpServletResponse sendRedirect to another app in the same app server

Tags: servlets, redirect

I have two apps deployed in my app server. Let's say they have the following urls

1. localhost:9080/App1
2. localhost:9080/App2

I have a filter in App2 which catches a certain request. When I catch this request I would want to forward it to a url in App2.

I know this can be done by

response.sendRedirect("http://somewhere");

but what if I do not want to hardcode "localhost:9080" in my codes since this would be dynamic and would change later on.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
response.sendRedirect("/relativePathToRedirect");
```

Relative redirects are allowed AFAIK

Please refer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

[Is a 302 Redirect to relative URL valid, or invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250259/is-a-302-redirect-to-relative-url-valid-or-invalid)